# How can I limit accessing my website's scripts for others?

Tags: php

I have a script which generates a avatar. Here is my structure:

```
-folder1
   -scripts
       -MakeAvatar.php
   -img
       -avatar
```

I use it in other pages like this:

```
$name = 'anything';
$hash = md5($name);
$input  = "http://localhost/folder1/scripts/MakeAvatar.php?hash=$hash";
$output = "../../folder1/img/avatar/".$name.".jpg";
file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
```

As you see, everybody can access this script and make a avatar:

```
http://localhost/folder1/scripts/MakeAvatar.php?hash=$hash
```

How can I devote that script just for my own website and forbid others to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the scripts outside the web root.

```
scripts
 -MakeAvatar.php
public (or whatever you call your webroot)
 -img
 -index.php
```

This means that www.site.com goes to the index.php, but you are unable to navigate to the scripts from a browser. *You* can, however, by doing:
`../scripts/MakeAvatar.php` (from index.php).

Comment: @stack That's actually an industry standard. If you ever get into MVCs or frameworks, you'll see that we tend to go out of our way to insulate as much of the site as possible from the user. To answer your question, no. Even if someone could see how you called the script (which they can't), unless they have server access (which they won't), they can not see the script.