# How can I access a script out of root by http protocol?

Tags: php

I have this folder-structure:

```
\out
    \script.php
\root
    \include
        \calculator.php
```

I need that script into `\calculator.php`. How can I include it?

```
// calculator.php
require( what path ? );
 ..
```

**Note:** I can include it by this path: `../out/script.php`. But I also need to pass a argument to `script.php`. So I want something like this:

```
.. what path/script.php?arg=value
```

And as you know, because I need to pass a argument to that, so I have to use `http` protocol. All I want to know, How can I use both `http` and `../`? Something like this:

```
http://../out/script.php?arg=value
```

Comment: No you can't access anything outside of root and its subfolders through a webbrower; although you can configure an alias in the web server that would allow you to access other folders

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually I can access something outside of root like this `../out/script.php`. But I don't know how can I both *pass a argument* and use `../`

Comment: Technically one could include a local script after overriding the request parameters. *Seldomly advisable.*

Comment: Your webserver should prevent you from accessing anything outside of root and its subfolders through a webbrowser.... otherwise Joe Hacker would be able to access any files on the server including password files, and that would be a serious security flaw that would destroy the www completely

Comment: @MarkBaker Look, I have fallowed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847008/how-can-i-limit-accessing-my-websites-scripts-for-others) approach. Is that bad?

Comment: @stack the link you followed says to use `../` in the script not in the browser

Comment: @NishanthMatha Yes .. I  need to use `../` in the script. *(I never want to access anything by browser)*. But because I also need to pass an argument, then I need to write `http` protocol. So how can I use both `http` protocol and `../` in script?

Comment: if you need to pass an argument to the script follow this standard:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters   You need not use `http` for it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass parameters when you include the script because it's loaded into the same scope as the first script. This means that the script ../out/script.php has access to the query string arguments through the $_GET variable:

```
$_GET['arg']
```

Also, any variables you define in calculator will be available in script.php

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate some variables inside the `$_GET` superglobal before you include your file, i.e.

```
$_GET['arg'] = "value";
require('../../out/script.php');
```

But that isn't ideal, in my opinion.

If I were you I'd use a boring 'ol global variable (assuming you start in the global scope):

```
$arg = 'value';
require('../../out/script.php');
```

Then simply use it like any other variable (maybe with some sanity checking, though):

```
if (!isset($arg)) {
    die('Oh my! $arg is not set! Error! Danger!');
}

do_something_with($arg);
```